Trouble integrating rlutil.h with Raylib in C++ game
I'm currently working on a C++ project using the Raylib library for game development. In this project, I want to incorporate functionalities provided by rlutil.h for console manipulation. However, I've encountered issues when trying to integrate rlutil.h with Raylib. Specifically, there seem to be conflicts or compatibility issues between the two libraries.
Problem Statement:
When including rlutil.h alongside Raylib headers in my project, I'm facing compilation errors or unexpected behavior. These issues occur even after attempting to resolve conflicts by adjusting include orders, using preprocessor directives, and inspecting potential naming clashes.
Specific Questions:
How can I effectively integrate rlutil.h with Raylib in my C++ project without encountering conflicts?
Are there any known compatibility issues between rlutil.h and Raylib that I should be aware of?
What steps can I take to debug and resolve conflicts between these libraries?
Or maybe some another library?
I am a begginner on C++.
Here is the repo :
https://github.com/lyes-hamici/CSDL/tree/file_manager
The structure of my project comes from :
https://github.com/educ8s/Raylib-CPP-Starter-Template-for-VSCODE-V2
I don't know where begin.
Here the compile errors example:
C:/raylib/w64devkit/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:3158:83: error: 'WINBOOL Rectangle(HDC, int, int, int, int)' redeclared as different kind of entity
3158 |   WINGDIAPI WINBOOL WINAPI Rectangle(HDC hdc,int left,int top,int right,int bottom);
|                                                                                   ^
In file included from src/main.cpp:1:
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:249:3: note: previous declaration 'typedef struct Rectangle Rectangle'
249 | } Rectangle;
|   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/raylib/w64devkit/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:72:
C:/raylib/w64devkit/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winuser.h:2282:29: error: conflicting declaration of C function 'WINBOOL CloseWindow(HWND)'
2282 |   WINUSERAPI WINBOOL WINAPI CloseWindow (HWND hWnd);
|                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:955:12: note: previous declaration 'void CloseWindow()'
955 | RLAPI void CloseWindow(void);                                     // Close window and unload OpenGL context
|            ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/raylib/w64devkit/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winuser.h:3760:25: error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int ShowCursor(WINBOOL)'
3760 |   WINUSERAPI int WINAPI ShowCursor(WINBOOL bShow);
|                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:1004:12: note: previous declaration 'void ShowCursor()'
1004 | RLAPI void ShowCursor(void);                                      // Shows cursor
|            ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:187:35: error: expected '}' before '{' token
187 | #define BLACK      CLITERAL(Color){ 0, 0, 0, 255 }         // Black
|                                   ^
src/rlutil.h:170:9: note: in expansion of macro 'BLACK'
170 |         BLACK,
|         ^~~~~
src/rlutil.h:169:6: note: to match this '{'
169 | enum {
|      ^
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:187:35: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
187 | #define BLACK      CLITERAL(Color){ 0, 0, 0, 255 }         // Black
|                                   ^
src/rlutil.h:170:9: note: in expansion of macro 'BLACK'
170 |         BLACK,
|         ^~~~~
src/rlutil.h:170:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
170 |         BLACK,
|              ^
C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.h:177:35: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '{' token
177 | #define BLUE       CLITERAL(Color){ 0, 121, 241, 255 }     // Blue
|                                   ^
src/rlutil.h:171:9: note: in expansion of macro 'BLUE'
171 |         BLUE,
|         ^~~~
Here some screenshots :
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

Edit your question with the actual compile errors you get and a [mre].

I have 127 errors, and the errors occurs on compiling

Then paste the first 10 along with the code that provokes them.

As text. Not as ~comments~ screenshots. (edited)

@Botje In what extend?

Sounds like you are actually clashing with the #include <windows.h> in rlutil.h, and it has  a known workaround

Okey, thank you, the fixes for this problem are complicated to my level of knowlege as I began to learn Programmation in september. Is there a way to call something like in python Raylib.Rectangle? To use explicit raylib methods and the rest window.h in order to avoid this confusion?

Given that all all three libraries are C and not C++ you cannot use the proper solution which is namespaces and explicit imports. Your best bet is to remove the windows.h include from rlutil and add the missing functions back in by hand. On top of that you will need to take care of any remaining naming conflicts by hand.
